# Autohotkey for VLC where scrolling affects video playback speed (eg. 1x 2x)

Tags: autohotkey, vlc

I had accomplished it somehow once before but since resetting my computer I can't figure out how to do it (I don't even know if I used autohotkey the first time but it seems to be my only choice now.)

So I'd like, when watching videos in VLC media player, that when I scroll up the video plays faster, and vice versa.

So far I've tried:

```
WheelUp::NumpadAdd
WheelDown::NumpadSub
```

while disabling the existing scroll functions in VLC, to no effect. Please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I forgot to simply reload the actual script I was adding onto. It works just fine lol
keeping this up incase it helps anyone else out! :3c